# install rokcketmq 4.3.2 for debian ,according to the official website,but could not "Start Name Server"

Tags: debian, rocketmq

tail -f ~/logs/rocketmqlogs/namesrv.log
exec the cmd ,but error

root@debian:/usr/local/mq/rocketmq-all-4.3.2# cd distribution/target/apache-rocketmq
root@debian:/usr/local/mq/rocketmq-all-4.3.2/distribution/target/apache-rocketmq# nohup sh bin/mqnamesrv &
[1] 1342
root@debian:/usr/local/mq/rocketmq-all-4.3.2/distribution/target/apache-rocketmq# nohup: 忽略输入并把输出追加到'nohup.out'
tail -f ~/logs/rocketmqlogs/namesrv.log
tail: 无法打开'/root/logs/rocketmqlogs/namesrv.log' 读取数据: 没有那个文件或目录
tail: 没有剩余文件
[1]+  退出 127              nohup sh bin/mqnamesrv
root@debian:/usr/local/mq/rocketmq-all-4.3.2/distribution/target/apache-rocketmq# tail -f ~/logs/rocketmqlogs/namesrv.log
tail: 无法打开'/root/logs/rocketmqlogs/namesrv.log' 读取数据: 没有那个文件或目录
tail: 没有剩余文件

Comment: a new question:when exec the cmd:closeChannel: close the connection to remote address[] result: true

Comment: a new question:tmq/bin# sh bin/mqbroker -m
sh: 0: Can't open bin/mqbroker